# WordPress font not loading when redirected using GoDaddy domain

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I am using aws ec2 instance for my worpress website. When I access my website using server IP address all the fonts work fine. But when I redirect the server IP address using GoDaddy domain, the actual font changes. I spoke to GoDaddy support and they said there is a problem at the hosting side. Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: First of all its easy tovuse AWS Lightsail gir WordPress hosting and its cost is less. Coming back to the issue can you check from browser consile whether the fonts path gives an error or not?

Comment: Paths are good. I copy and pasted the path on browser and it either shows me the font file on browser or give me the prompt to download the font file.